# How to show Clayton copula is continuous and decreasing at $\theta=-1$?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, finance, copula

Clayton copula is defined as
\begin{align*}C_{\theta}(x,y) =& \text{ } (max(x^{-\theta}+y^{-\theta} - 1),0)^{-\frac{1}{\theta}} \text{ if } (x,y) \in (0,1]^2\\
=& \text{ }0 \text{ otherwise}
\end{align*}
$\forall \text{ } \theta \in [-1,\infty]- \{0\}$.

How to show that this is continuous and decreasing as $\theta\to-1^{+}$ for every pair $(x,y) \in [0,1]^2$?

Note: I faced this problem while solving a problem on Clayton copula. I could show the decreasing property by taking derivative wrt $\theta$ when the derivative exists (a more general method will be appreciated) but cannot show continuity at all.

Edits: I forgot to mention that Clayton copula is undefined at $\theta=0$ (though it exists when $\theta\rightarrow 0$ and is known as product copula). Also, the definition of copula given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory) and in Nelsen's book "An Introduction to Copulas" define Clayton copula as
\begin{align*}
C_{\theta}(x,y) = \text{ } (max(x^{-\theta}+y^{-\theta} - 1),0)^{-\frac{1}{\theta}} \text{ }\forall \text{ }\theta \in [-1,\infty]- \{0\} \text{ where }(x,y)\in[0,1]^2.
\end{align*}

But, I think it should be defined separately when at least one of the arguments is 0 because copulas are bivariate CDF with uniform marginal distribution.

Comment: It is important to express the formula correctly, so I fixed it for you.  I also made minor changes to reflect the fact that this formula for $C_\theta$ is *undefined* for $\theta=-1.$  The continuity follows immediately from the fact that the derivatives exist.  All you really need to show is that the limiting values actually constitute a copula.

Comment: I actually made a mistake in the definition but that is not what you said. I have cited the references in the edits regarding the definition. At $\theta=-1$, it is very much defined and is called counter-monotonicity copula or maximum copula.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write "0" rather than "-1".  So: given $C$ is expressed in terms of three variables $x,y,\theta,$ what exactly do you want to show is continuous?  And, once again, since you have taken the derivative with respect to $\theta,$ $C$ must at least be continuous in $\theta$--but because for $\theta\ne 0$ $C$ is expressed as a composition of continuous functions, there's little left to show.

Comment: I want to show given any $(x,y)\in[0,1]^2$, $lim_{\theta \downarrow -1^+}C_{\theta}(x,y)=C_{-1}(x,y)$. The way I did it by taking derivative is not a rigorous way. Derivative can be surely taken for all $(x,y)\in [0,1]^2$ if $\theta>0$. Otherwise, it is not possible to take derivatives for any $(x,y)$.